# Ubuntu Graphical login freeze

Tags: gnome, 22.04, login, lxde

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with no GUI envirovment. The OS has been just installed and no modification to the standard version downloadable from the website have been made.

I've recently installed lxde with the classic `sudo apt-get install lxde` as I wanted to use it with xrdp for remote access (installed via `sudo apt-get install xrdp`)

I've set xrdp to use lxde when logged in with xorg with the following code

```
sudo apt install -y xrdp openbox-lxde-session
sudo sed -e 's/^new_cursors=true/new_cursors=false/g' \
     -i /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo systemctl restart xrdp

echo "startlxde" > ~/.xsession
```

Now, If I connect a montiro, mouse and keyboard and turn on the PC, the classic gnome login page shows up (see screenshot) but it freeze instantly (the mouse pointer doesn't show up, the cursor stop blinking and nothing work). If I connect with the remote monitor that uses lxde, everything works perfectly

[image]

How can I make the standard lxde login page and envirovement to be used on startup?

Comment: Are we to assume you're running Ubuntu Server (which comes with no DE)? What other modifications have you made?

Comment: @Esther none. it's a clean installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out I needed to install this to get keyboard and mouse work and don't make freeze the login screen

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```